# Image.FromFile("image_path") throws the out of memory exception for some of the JPEG file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am generating the thumbnail after downloading the image from external URL. The url has the path of the JPEG image. When I create the thumbnail for the jpeg image , thumbnail has been generated for some of the JPEG image and its not generated for some JPEG image. I am unable to find the root cause that why its not working for some JPEG image. Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
        try
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile("image_Path");

            int srcWidth = image.Width;
            int srcHeight = image.Height;
            int thumbWidth = width;
            int thumbHeight = 0;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(72, 72);

            if (srcHeight > srcWidth)
            {
                thumbHeight = (srcHeight / srcWidth) * thumbWidth;
                bmp = new Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                thumbHeight = thumbWidth;
                thumbWidth = (srcWidth / srcHeight) * thumbHeight;
                bmp = new Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
            }

            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
            Rectangle rectDestination = new Rectangle(0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
            gr.DrawImage(image, rectDestination, 0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            bmp.Save(destinationfile);
            bmp.Dispose();
            image.Dispose();
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            //bmp.Dispose();
            //image.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: One "problem" is you create a bitmap `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(72, 72);` then you create another one `bmp = new Bitmap(thumbWidth, thumbHeight);` without disposing the former one `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(72, 72);` should be `Bitmap bmp;` instead. Don't allocate if it is not required.

Comment: @Kwiksilver
I am getting the exception from the First line. 
Image image = Image.FromFile("image_Path");

Comment: If you read the documentation for [`Image.FromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=net-5.0) you will see under the Exception section it mentions the reason for throwing a [`OutOfMemoryException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=net-5.0). The reason is `The file does not have a valid image format.`-or-`GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.` My guess is your `"image_Path"` is not a valid image.